# Fantasy book about about a town where some people had “dragon powers”

Tags: story-identification, books, dragons

I believe it was a book about a town where some people had “dragon powers”. Our main character and his brother both get these powers after laying in the sun too long or something. The powers included mind reading and some other things. The MC starts abusing his powers and becoming more dragon-like, so his brother (with a pastor or something) have to try to stop/save him.

I think there were 4-5 with these powers in the story, a woman and 3-4 men including the MC and brother.

Comment: Can you roughly remember when you read this? Did they save the brother? Did he turn into a dragon? How was he abusing the powers? If you want to add anything else to the post you can [edit] it.

Comment: Did a subplot involve a police detective trying to track down a killer who burned his victims to death?